# Validação de Formulário - PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer a validação de um e-mail para o envio de um formulário em [php](/questions/tagged/php), mas está difícil. Meu código está abaixo, onde estou errando?

```
 $subject2 = utf8_decode ('Formulário 2016 - PRE-CADASTRO');
 $body2 = $mensagem_confirmacao;

 if (filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
 {      
     if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {    
         mail($mail, $subject2, $body2, $headers);
         echo "<p>Inscrição enviada com sucesso!</p>";
    } else {
         echo "<p>Erro no envio, Houve algum erro no envio.Tente Novamente ";
    }

 } else { 
     echo "<p>E-mail ".$mail." inválido <a href='inscreva-se.php'>Houve algum erro no envio.Tente Novamente</a>!</p>"; 
 }
```

Comment: amigo é interessante colocar qual o problema que esta ocorrendo para podermos ser mais precisos

Comment: Ele quer fazer a validação de emails @Otto

Comment: essa parte eu entendi @Danilo o que esta dificil entender é qual problema esta tendo pois a sintaxe do filter_var esta correta a principio. Quanto mais infoormação melhor né amigo, na maioria das vezes na mensagem de erro esta a solução.

Comment: @paulorpc qual é o erro em especifico? posta para te ajudarmos.

Comment: então amigos o erro pode ser visualizado nesse form: http://www.abimo.org.br/premioinovasaude/increva-se.php eu preencho todos os campos e quando clico para enviar ele da a mensagem que o "email é invalido" e não envia nda

Answer (score 0):

Não sei exatamente qual o seu problema, mas o if do mail() está duplicado.
O correto seria assim:

```
if ( mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ) 
{    
   echo "<p>Inscrição enviada com sucesso!</p>";
}
else
{
   echo "<p>Erro no envio, Houve algum erro no envio.Tente Novamente</p> ";
}
```

Comment: quando tento enviar o formulário a mensagem do segundo echo aparece e não me deixa enviar. se possivel olha o link: http://www.abimo.org.br/premioinovasaude/increva-se.php

Comment: paulorpc isso é bom, digo isso porque significa que o código acima está funcionando. Eu explico: Se está aparecendo a mensagem do echo do else é porque o function mail() está retornando false.
O que precisa ser visto então é a configuração do serviço de e-mail configurado no php.ini (ex: /usr/sbin/sendmail).
Outra alternativa para enviar e-mail pelo PHP é PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer com ele você pode configurar um servidor externo como o gmail